# Define key inside dolist

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I am trying to avoid duplicating code and also trying to avoid introducing unnecessary global symbols. So I tried to use `let`, `dolist` and `lambda` when defining the same keys in two different keymaps:

```
(let ((key (kbd "S-<down>"))
      (def (lambda ()
             (interactive)
             (unless (evil-visual-state-p)
               (evil-visual-state))
             (evil-next-line))))
  (dolist (map '(evil-normal-state-map evil-insert-state-map))
    (define-key map key def)))
```

Here I want `S-down` to have the same definition in both `evil-normal-state-map` and in `evil-insert-state-map`.

This gives me error:

```
Wrong type argument: keymapp, evil-normal-state-map
```

Comment: Think I found the error: I need to use `symbol-value` on the list variable `map`: `(define-key (symbol-value map) key def)`. Still curious why I need to do that :)

Comment: `define-key` requires the keymap itself and not some symbol but you iterate over the symbols with your `dolist`. `eval` would also do instead of `symbol-value`.

Comment: Or iterate over keymaps instead of symbols: `(dolist (map (list evil-normal-state-map evil-insert-state-map))...`

Comment: I find this curious--most functions take some value *or* a symbol with some value. *Only* accepting a value is inconvenient, to say the least.

Comment: @tianxiang-xiong: I'm curious: could you give an example of such a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Chapter 2](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lisp-Data-Types.html) : *"Lisp Data Types"*, of the Emacs Lisp manual:

> Each object belongs to one and only one primitive type. These types
>   include integer, float, cons, symbol, string, vector, hash-table,
>   subr, and byte-code function, plus several special types, such as
>   buffer, that are related to editing.

and from [Chapter 2.3.6](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cell-Type.html#Cons-Cell-Type) : *"Cons Cell and List Types"* :

> A cons cell is an object that consists of two slots, called the CAR
>   slot and the CDR slot. Each slot can hold any Lisp object. We also say
>   that the CAR of this cons cell is whatever object its CAR slot
>   currently holds, and likewise for the CDR. A list is a series of cons
>   cells, linked together so that the CDR slot of each cons cell holds
>   either the next cons cell or the empty list. The empty list is
>   actually the symbol nil. Because cons cells are so central to Lisp, we
>   also have a word for an object which is not a cons cell. These objects
>   are called atoms.

And from [Chapter 21.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-of-Keymaps.html) : *"Format of Keymaps"*:

> Each keymap is a list whose CAR is the symbol keymap. The remaining
>   elements of the list define the key bindings of the keymap. A symbol
>   whose function definition is a keymap is also a keymap. Use the
>   function keymapp (see below) to test whether an object is a keymap.

When I quote an object, I get an object of type `symbol`, whereas a keymap is an object of primitive type `cons`, type `list`, and constructed type `keymap`.

The `define-key` function expects a first argument of type `keymap`. This is checked by `define-key` using the `keymapp` predicate function. If the argument is not of type `keymap`, it will throw an exception.

According to [Chapter 8.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#Symbol-Components) : *"Symbol Components"* :

> Each symbol has four components (or “cells”), each of which references
>   another object:
>
> **Print name**
>   The symbol’s name.
>
> **Value**
>   The symbol’s current value as a variable.
>
> **Function**
>   The symbol’s function definition. It can also hold a symbol,
>   a keymap, or a keyboard macro.
>
> **Property list**
>   The symbol’s property list.
>
> The print name cell always holds a string, and cannot be changed. Each
>   of the other three cells can be set to any Lisp object.

According to [Chapter 9.5](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html) : *"Eval"* :

> **Eval**
>
> Most often, forms are evaluated automatically, by virtue of their
>   occurrence in a program being run. On rare occasions, you may need to
>   write code that evaluates a form that is computed at run time, such as
>   after reading a form from text being edited or getting one from a
>   property list. On these occasions, use the eval function. Often eval
>   is not needed and something else should be used instead. For example,
>   to get the value of a variable, while eval works, symbol-value is
>   preferable

When I do [`dolist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html) on a [`quoted`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) 
list of keymaps, I get a list of objects of type `symbol`, whereas each symbol's value slot has a keymap object. Hence, my problem can be solved by passing each symbol's value to `define-key`, instead of the symbol itself.

According to the comments by @Tobias and @npostavs, there are many ways to solve my problem. For example, we could solve this using either `symbol-value`, `eval`, or `list`. Hence, the following three examples will all pass an object of type `keymap` as first argument to `lookup-key`:

```
(dolist (kmap '(global-map))
  (message-box "%s" (lookup-key (symbol-value kmap) (kbd "C-h"))))
(dolist (kmap '(global-map))
  (message-box "%s" (lookup-key (eval kmap) (kbd "C-h"))))
(dolist (kmap (list global-map))
  (message-box "%s" (lookup-key kmap (kbd "C-h"))))
```

Comment: The last option, the one that passes dolist a list of keymaps instead of a list of symbols, is much, much better than the others. It expresses intent more directly: "for each keymap, add this binding" vs "for each of these names of keymaps, lookup which keymap is named by it and add this binding".