# Why doesn't my keymap let-binding work?

Tags: let-binding

I'm trying to define the keymap for a major mode but keep getting the error: `Wrong type argument: keymapp`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
(defun insert-text ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((x (read-string "Enter text to be printed: ")))
    (insert x)))

(defvar test-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "M-S-RET") 'insert-text)))

(defun test-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (setq major-mode 'test-mode
    mode-name  "Test Mode")
  (use-local-map test-mode-map))
```

I read [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/define-key-inside-dolist) with a similar error but it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `let`-binding of your `defvar` form.

The `let` will return the value of its last form.  Currently, the
last form is `define-key`, which returns the function symbol
which you bound to the keys.

Instead, you want to return the `map` you created:

```
(defvar test-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "M-S-RET") 'insert-text)
    map))                           ; need to return the keymap

(keymapp test-mode-map)             ; => t
```

Comment: That solves the keymapp error, but when I press "M-S-RET" I get "M-RET is undefined". Is the keybinding not allowed?

Comment: @Jacek: for this site, we try to keep questions and answers discrete rather than do a lot of follow-up through comments.  I'd suggest you work with the keybinding in question for a while and try other options to isolate the problem.  If you still have problems after a while, post a second, discrete question about it.

Comment: Try `(kbd "M-S-<return>")`.